# Divide number with two percentages

Tags: javascript, math

I have two percentages, lets say 20% and 25%.
then I have a number, lets say 100.

```js
var x = 20;
var y = 25;
var number = 100;
```

How do I divide the number with x,y so that the remainder of number is 0 and x,y keep their ratio towards eachother?

Comment: `var scale = number/(x+y); x *= scale; y *= scale;`

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. what does split mean in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you want to keep the ratio between `x` and `y` while scaling them so that

xs+ys = number

where `xs` is `x` after scaling, and `ys` is `y` after scaling.

the easiest way would be to just multiply both `x` and `y` by the same value(scaling factor). If you just multiply both of them with the same value you will keep the ratio between them unchanged.

Finding the (scaling factor) -we'll just call it `sfactor`- is quite easy, just divide `number` by `x+y` to get the scaling factor`sfactor`

> sfactor = number/(x+y);

and then just multiply both of `x` and `y` by 'sfactor':

> var xs = sfactor*x;
>
> var ys = sfactor*y;

This way `xs+ys= number`, and `xs/ys = x/y` which is what -I think- you want.